# How to use Attributes to control the serialization of a property in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes, deserialization

I would like to control how a particular class serializes it's data... for example:

```
    [TimeSeriesSerialization(TimeSeriesSerializationType.Dates)]
    public TimeSeries DailyValues { get; set; }

    [TimeSeriesSerialization(TimeSeriesSerializationType.Normal)]
    public TimeSeries IntraDayValues { get; set; }
```

In my example here, I have a class called TimeSeries that has a List of DateTimes and a List of decimals... when I serialize it I want to do two things... create a JSON string that is a set of time/value pairs... for example:

```
{"2018-01-30T09:30:01":9958.2289,"2018-01-30T09:30:02":9958.2284,...}
```

But I would also like to have the option to serialize this class as Date values (without the time)... as so:

```
{"2018-01-30":9958.2289,"2018-01-31":9958.2284,...}
```

Or as only values:

```
[9958.2289,9958.2284,...]
```

Any help?

```
public enum TimeSeriesSerializationType
{
    Times,
    Dates,
    ValuesOnly,
}

public class TimeSeries
{
    public List<DateTime> Times = new List<DateTime>();
    public List<decimal> Values = new List<decimal>();

    public void Add(DateTime time, decimal value)
    {
        Times.Add(time);
        Values.Add(value);
    }

    public string Serialize(TimeSeriesSerializationType timeSeriesSerializationType)
    {
        switch (timeSeriesSerializationType)
        {
            case TimeSeriesSerializationType.Dates:
                {
                    var data = new Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>();
                    for (var i = 0; i < Times.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!data.ContainsKey(Times[i])) // duplicate dates???
                            data.Add(Times[i], Values[i]);
                    }
                    var isoDateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" };
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None, isoDateTimeConverter);
                    return json;
                }
            case TimeSeriesSerializationType.ValuesOnly:
                {
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Values, Formatting.None);
                    return json;
                }
            default:
                {
                    var data = new Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>();
                    for (var i = 0; i < Times.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!data.ContainsKey(Times[i])) // duplicate times???
                            data.Add(Times[i], Values[i]);
                    }
                    var isoDateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz" };
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None, isoDateTimeConverter);
                    return json;
                }
        }
    }

    public void Deserialize(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return;
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>>(str);
        if (data.Count <= 0) return;
        foreach (var d in data)
            this.Add(d.Key, d.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already have most of what you need.
What's missing is the attribute itself.

You'd define it like this (you can read more about the AttributeUsage-Attribute [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/attributeusage)):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
class TimeSeriesSerializationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TimeSeriesSerializationType SerializationType { get; }

    public TimeSeriesSerializationAttribute(TimeSeriesSerializationType timeSeriesSerializationType)
    {
        SerializationType = timeSeriesSerializationType;
    }
}
```

Now you can add those above your properties just like you already wrote.

Time for the evaluation part. You can use something like this to read all the properties and use them to serialize your TimeSeries.
By the way if the attribute you get turns out as null, the attribute just isn't set. You can either skip the property entirely or use a default SerializationType, whatever you need/want.

```
public static void SerializeToSomewhere(YourClassWithTimeSeries instance) {
    // get all public, instance properties 
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> allProps = typeof(YourClassWithTimeSeries).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    // only take TimeSeries-properties
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> timeSeriesProps = allProps.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TimeSeries));

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in timeSeriesProps)
    {
        // get the attribute
        TimeSeriesSerializationAttribute attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<TimeSeriesSerializationAttribute>();
        if (attribute == null) continue; // or do something else like use a default SerializationType

        // get the value
        TimeSeries value = (TimeSeries)property.GetValue(instance, null);

        // serialize using the type from the attribute
        string serializedValue = value.Serialize(attribute.SerializationType);
        // Do whatever with the serialized value (for example save it to a file or whatever)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. There are also plenty of attribute tutorials and docs if you need additional information. I'll also try to answer questions you might have so feel free to ask.

Edit:
Small thing to add. In your code your TimeSeries-class exposes the public fields Times and Values. You shouldn't do that. 
Instead of doing this:

```
public List<DateTime> Times = new List<DateTime>();
public List<decimal> Values = new List<decimal>();
```

You should do this. It stops you from accidentally assigning it again from within or outside the class.

```
public List<DateTime> Times { get; } = new List<DateTime>();
public List<decimal> Values { get; } = new List<decimal>();
```

Comment: Yes... I pretty much was there except for where does the "foreach (PropertyInfo property in timeSeriesProps)" code go... in the serialization of the class where the properties are defined?

Comment: Also... I like the "{ get; } = new..." style... never saw that before!

Comment: Wherever you want to be frank. You can wrap it into a function and then call it from anywhere you want. This wouldn't matter then. Wait let me edit the answer.

Comment: I've now edited my answer. As you can see I just created a method around the code I already posted. You can call it with an instance of the "particular class" you never showed and within the method you can use the serialized strings to do whatever you want with them. It doesn't matter where you place this method and as long as I don't know the bigger picture of you application I can't really help you with where to place it exactly but I think in the "particular class" where the TimeSeries-properties are probably.

Answer (score 0):

A more pedestrian, but effective approach(for json)...

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public PriceSeries DailyValues { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DailyValues")]
    public string DailyValuesSerialized {
        get
        {
            return (DailyValues == null) ?
                null : 
                DailyValues.Serialize(TimeSeriesSerializationType.ValuesOnly);
        }
        set
        {
            DailyValues = (value == null) ? null : new PriceSeries(value);
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public PriceSeries IntraDayValues { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "IntraDayValues")]
    public string IntraDayValuesSerialized
    {
        get
        {
            return (IntraDayValues == null) ?
                null : 
                IntraDayValues.Serialize(TimeSeriesSerializationType.Normal);
        }
        set
        {
            IntraDayValues = (value == null) ? null : new PriceSeries(value);
        }
    }
```

Or this (for a database)...

```
    [NotMapped]
    public PriceSeries DailyValues { get; set; }
    [Column("DailyValues")]
    public string DailyValuesSerialized
    {
        get
        {
            return (DailyValues == null) ?
                null :
                DailyValues.Serialize(TimeSeriesSerializationType.ValuesOnly);
        }
        set
        {
            DailyValues = (value == null) ? null : new PriceSeries(value);
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public PriceSeries IntraDayValues { get; set; }
    [Column("IntraDayValues")]
    public string IntraDayValuesSerialized
    {
        get
        {
            return (IntraDayValues == null) ?
                null :
                IntraDayValues.Serialize(TimeSeriesSerializationType.Normal);
        }
        set
        {
            IntraDayValues = (value == null) ? null : new PriceSeries(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see how this would work but it seems like this is a different use case right?. You aren't using any custom attributes here and I thought that was the whole point of your question. Sorry for misunderstanding and thanks for still accepting my answer.

Comment: For me the primary objective was to get my object PriceSeries to serialize in several different formats... it seemed to my that an attribute would be the cleanest and most elegant way... you did give me the way of doing that (which is why I marked your answer correct)... unfortunately this involved having to write other code in order to get the container of the object(s) to serialize... in my example it's all contained in the object itself... and the actual serializing is then handle by entity framework and/or newtonsoft like always.

Comment: Ahh I see. I didn't catch that you want EF/Newtonsoft to be able to understand the attribute.